# wkhtmltopdf is working via terminal, but not via PHP

Tags: php, windows, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to create a PDF file from the HTML page that I created, and for that I'm using wkhtmltopdf.
For some reason, when I try to call the exec() function, wkhtmltopdf will run indefinitely. In the last test I left it running for 10 minutes until I killed the process.

The problem occurs when I try to use as source absolutely any page within the project.
When I execute the command via terminal, using Google as the source, the PDF is generated.
When I execute the command via terminal, using my page as a source, the PDF is generated.
When I execute the command via PHP, using Google as the source, the PDF is generated.
When I execute the command via PHP, using my page as a source, the PDF is **not** generated.

The code I have is simple:

```
<?php
exec('"C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe" http://google.com/ test.pdf 2>error.txt');
exec('"C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe" http://localhost:8000/info.php test2.pdf 2>error.txt');
?>
```

The first call to the exec() function is working perfectly, but the second call is not.
The error.txt file looks like this:

```
Loading pages (1/6)  
[>                                                           ] 0%  
[======>                                                     ] 10%
```

Would anyone know why the second call is not working?
I appreciate the help.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem when I try to execute the command with the cookie parameter. It works on the command line but exec() method from PHP.
`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --cookie PHPSESSID 'somesessionid' https://example.com/createpdf.php test.pdf`

Exact same command is working via the command line but PHP. Any thoughts or solutions you found so far? Thanks.

Comment: My problem's solution is closing the session (session_write_close command) right before the exec call. This way, the script doesn't have to wait for the other one to be finished, and exec() works in the caller script. 
Link: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/issues/250#issuecomment-335781845